# Why am I getting this error during DevKit install for ROR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, devkit, libv8

I am using both `--force` and without. still no dice. This all started because im trying to install twitter bootstrap which was having issues during `GEM libv8` install.....supposedely that was a result of not having `DevKit`

```
C:\DevKit>ruby dk.rb install --force
    [INFO] Updating convenience notice gem override for 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Hero
    ku/ruby-1.9.3'
    dk.rb:83:in `rename': Permission denied - (C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/ruby-1.
    9.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/defaults/operating_system.rb, C:/Program F
    iles (x86)/Heroku/ruby-1.9.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/defaults/operatin
    g_system.rb.20140911155540) (Errno::EACCES)
            from dk.rb:83:in `update_gem_override'
            from dk.rb:257:in `block (2 levels) in install'
            from dk.rb:243:in `each'
            from dk.rb:243:in `block in install'
            from dk.rb:216:in `each'
            from dk.rb:216:in `install'
            from dk.rb:310:in `run'
            from dk.rb:329:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem and was able to get around it by running the command-line as Administrator.

Right-click command line -> Run as Administrator. This was on Windows 7 32-bit